# C# EF Core Razor pages Entity Framework CRUD: There was an error running the selected code generator: Could not get the reflection type for DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am doing Razor Pages using EF Core. And I did several times scaffolding and it was OK, but after several commits I started gettign this error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: Could not get the reflection type for DbContext

[image]

WHY? What happened with scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

It was `unsafe { }` block in the C# code.

---

After commenting **unsafe** code, EF scaffolding can be run successfully.